# Mover o mouse via programação

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Mover mouse para controle (exemplo um button) no *Delphi* com *Firemonkey*.

Tentei esta função:

```
procedure TFuncoes.MouseParaControle(Controle: TControl);
var                // Posiciona o mouse em cima do objeto definido em 
  IrPara: TPoint;  // Ex.: MouseParaControle(button1);
begin
  IrPara.X := Controle.Position.X + (Controle.Size.width div 2); // ERRO
  IrPara.Y := Controle.Position.y + (Controle.size.Height div 2);// ERRO
  if Controle.Parent <> nil then
    begin
      IrPara := Controle.PointInObjectLocal(irPara.x, irPara.Y);       
      //Parent.ClientToScreen(IrPara);
      SetCursorPos(IrPara.X, IrPara.Y);
    end;
end;
```

**ERRO:**

> [dcc32 Error] Trp.Model.Funcoes.pas(214): E2015 Operator not
>   applicable to this operand type na linha

Comment: se consegui ajudar com a minha resposta, pode aceitar a resposta clicando no ✔ no lado esquerdo da mesma. Se necessitar de alguma mais ajuda avise.

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
procedure TForm1.BtnClicarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Chama a função e passa o controller que desejar
  MouseaParaController(BtnAqui);
end;

Procedure TForm1.MouseaParaController(Controle: TControl);
var IrPara: TPoint; // Posiciona o mouse em cima do objeto definido em Ex.: MouseParaControle(button1);
    BarCaptionHeight, BarLeftWidth: Integer;
begin
  //defenir tamanhos das bordas
  BarCaptionHeight := 30; //tamanho aproximado do caption
  BarLeftWidth := 5; //tamanho aproximado do border

  //pegar a posição do componente(botão neste caso)
  IrPara.X := Form1.Left + Controle.Left + BarLeftWidth + (Controle.Width div 2);
  IrPara.Y := Form1.Top + Controle.Top + BarCaptionHeight + (Controle.Height div 2);

  //mandar o mouse para a posição
  if Controle.Parent <> nil then SetCursorPos(IrPara.X, IrPara.Y);
End;
```

`Form1.Left` vai pegar o valor entre o inicio do monitor até ao form.
`Controle.Left` vai pegar o valor do fim do border até ao componente.
`BarLeftWidth` vai pegar o valor do border.
`Controle.Width div 2` vai pegar o valor do inicio do componente até ao centro.

Vou ainda tentar arranjar forma não precisar declarar as variáveis com o tamanho dos border do form.

Comment: Na VCL funciona mas FMX não.

Comment: @JairSilveira não tenho nenhuma versão recente com FireMonkey, mas vou pesquisar um pouco e ver se consigo ajudar mais, está a dar algum erro em especifico?

Comment: @JairSilveira, vê isto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224549/mouse-coordinates-to-caret-position-in-firemonkey-tmemo-component

Comment: @Tmc, mude a variavel `IrPara` de `TPoint` para TRect, dessa forma você poderá acessar as posições `top, bottom, left, right`do compoente ;D